# Java Socket consumes 100% CPU

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket that is consuming 100% of the computer's CPU.
There are 150 clients sending messages to the server every 30 seconds unsynchronously.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Below is my ServerSocket class

```
public class Servidor { 

  static ExecutorService es;    

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(150);
    ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(2010);

    while (true) {
      Socket soquete = null;

      try {
        System.out.println("Aguardando cliente: ");
        soquete = servidor.accept();
        System.out.println("Cliente Conectado: ");
        es.execute(new Conexao(soquete));

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 

    }

  }

}
```

The Conexao class (utility class) takes the string sent by the clients and saves it in the database.
Below my Conexao class

```
public class Conexao implements Runnable{

    Socket soquete;
    int contador = 0;

    public Conexao(Socket soquete) {
        super();
        this.soquete = soquete;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        BufferedReader in = null;

        try{            
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soquete.getInputStream()));                   

            while (!in.ready()) {/*System.out.println("!in.ready()");*/}

            String str =in.readLine();

            System.out.println("Rodando Thread"+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : texto: " + str);                     

        }finally{               
            ...

            if(soquete != null){
                try {
                    soquete.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }           
        }       
}


}
```

Comment: There's no need to declare `soquete` everytime you go through the loop

Comment: Where is the source for Conexao?

Comment: when you say you have "_a socket that is consuming 100% of the computer's CPU_" – how are you reaching that conclusion? also, as @BenjaminUrquhart pointed out, you should move `Socket soquete` outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: Conexao is a class that takes customer information "soquete.getInputStream()" and writes the message to the database.

Comment: When I leave this socket listening to clients for a day it occupies the whole CPU, I run the htop command on linux and see all CPU cores in 100% usage. if I restart the socket the cpu return to normal.

Comment: From what I can tell, you don't ever close the socket. That's definitely a red flag for me

Comment: There is nothing obvious in this code example. I would look at `Conexao` next. If you can recreate the scenario, try hooking up [Visual VM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) to see which threads are active, how much memory is in use, which functions are being used, etc.

Comment: This will uselessly consume CPU time: `while (!in.ready()) {/*System.out.println("!in.ready()");*/}`. Remove it.

Comment: I'm very close to downvote this topic. There is plenty of examples online about how to write client-server applications (as simple as this one) and with good practices + so good frameworks around to write nice effective code (eg. Netty). Here I don't think its necessary to allocate 150 threads for such very small tasks (except if you expect some requests to hang..) and if some request hang it will enter a while loop without any sleep time or instruction (hence consuming CPU for nothing). You should instead block for a number of bytes or a marker or queue read bytes or queries, etc..

Comment: Two last comments: some design is quite wrong and, f.i. if clients start misbehaving you will slowly run into issues. Consider also using timeouts if you don't want to exhaust your connections, threads, handles and let the CPU breath a bit in your loops :)

Comment: I solved the problem by removing part "while (!in.ready()) {/*System.out.println("!in.ready()");*/}" and creating a "Thread.sleep" at the end of the try block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing part "while (!in.ready()) {/*System.out.println("!in.ready()");*/}" and creating a "Thread.sleep" at the end of the try block

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, then add it to your answer, do not correct the problem in your question itself.

Comment: @mark rotteveel do you really think this is "the right answer" to this question?

Comment: @JonasWilms Why do you think I think this is the right answer? I posted my comment because the OP posted this answer, and then proceeded to edit the code in their question with their fix (which I rolled back). That said, using `while(!in.ready)` is a hot-loop which can lead to 100% CPU usage until you receive data, so in that sense, this probably is a right answer.